# Binding a List in a ObservableCollection in XAML - Specified cast not valid exception

Tags: list, xamarin.forms, binding

I have an `ObservableCollection<List<Model>> Data` in my `ViewModel`.
In my `Page` I need a `CarouselView`, in which each `ItemTemplate` shows the data of the `Data` list in a `ListView`.
Currently, I am doing that in that way:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                ...
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                    ...
                </ListView>
             </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

In the way I am doing that I get a "Specified cast not valid" exception, in which I see the following additional information:

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].ActivateContent (System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00032]
 in <62e3629c74b84e3d834046331d2bb5f8>:0
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].CreateContent (System.Int32 index, System.Object item, System.Boolean insert) [0x00000]
 in <62e3629c74b84e3d834046331d2bb5f8>:0
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].GetOrCreateContent (System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00023]
 in <62e3629c74b84e3d834046331d2bb5f8>:0
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x0000e]
 in <62e3629c74b84e3d834046331d2bb5f8>:0
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCellForPath (Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00007]
 in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1397
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00021]
 in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1105
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) [0x0003b]
 in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:85
   at App.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001]
 in <Path>\Main.cs:18 }
```

The Model holds only `string` values, so the exception cannot come from this.

Comment: is the error from the Carosuel or the ListView?  If its the ListView, what does it's template look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting that specific exception. I couldn't get the `ListView` inside of a `CarouselView` to work either.

However, it works when you use a bindable `StackLayout` instead of a `ListView`. My guess is that the bindable `StackLayout` doesn't support scrolling and thus doesn't fight with the `CarouselView` but I don't know.

MainPage, MainViewModel and items

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Data { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<Item>(GenerateItems());
        }

        private IEnumerable<Item> GenerateItems()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                .Select(a => new Item
                {
                    ItemTitle = $"Item {a}",
                    SubItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(b => new SubItem { SubItemTitle = $"SubItem {b}" }).ToList()
                });
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }

        public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubItem
    {
        public string SubItemTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemTitle}" />
                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding SubItemTitle}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>

</ContentPage>
```

Result:

[image]